# ApolloHttpException: HTTP 401 while using AWS Appsync with IAM auth mode in Android app

Tags: android, graphql, amazon-cognito, aws-appsync, amazon-iam

I am trying to integrate an Appsync Graphql api, that has AWS_IAM auth mode, into an Android app. I have followed the AWS documentation related to this but I'm getting the ApolloHttpException: HTTP 401 error.

```
2018-10-19 09:38:34.853 4679-4739/io.xxxxxxx.android.cognitoiamtest E/AWS: Failed to perform AllPostsQuery
com.apollographql.apollo.exception.ApolloHttpException: HTTP 401 
    at com.apollographql.apollo.internal.interceptor.ApolloParseInterceptor.parse(ApolloParseInterceptor.java:147)
    at com.apollographql.apollo.internal.interceptor.ApolloParseInterceptor.access$100(ApolloParseInterceptor.java:54)
    at com.apollographql.apollo.internal.interceptor.ApolloParseInterceptor$1.onResponse(ApolloParseInterceptor.java:83)
    at com.apollographql.apollo.internal.interceptor.ApolloServerInterceptor$1$1.onResponse(ApolloServerInterceptor.java:110)
    at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:141)
    at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Appsync client code:

```
val awsConfig = AWSConfiguration(context)

val credentialsProvider = CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(context, awsConfig)

client = AWSAppSyncClient.builder()
                .context(context)
                .awsConfiguration(awsConfig)
                .credentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
                .build()
```

My awsconfiguration.json

```
{
    "UserAgent": "aws-amplify-cli/0.1.0",
    "Version": "1.0",
    "IdentityManager": {
    "Default": {}
    },
    "CredentialsProvider": {
        "CognitoIdentity": {
            "Default": {
                "PoolId": "xx-xxxx-x:xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx",
                "Region": "xx-xxxx-x"
            }
        }
    },
    "CognitoUserPool": {
        "Default": {
            "PoolId": "xx-xxxxx-x_xxxxxx",
            "AppClientId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "AppClientSecret": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "Region": "xx-xxxxx-x"
        }
    },
    "AppSync": {
        "Default": {
            "ApiUrl": "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.appsync-api.xx-xxxxx-x.amazonaws.com/graphql",
            "Region": "xx-xxxxx-x",
            "AuthMode": "AWS_IAM",
            "ApiKey": "xxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        }
    }
}
```

I have also added the following policy to the authenticated role in Identity Pool.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
            "appsync:GraphQL"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:appsync:xx-xxxx-x:xxxxxxxxx:apis/CognitoIAMTest/types/Query/fields/listCities"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Though there are very less resources for Appsync with IAM auth for Android but I have tried whatever I could find online. I am not sure what I'm missing. Any help regarding this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did this ever get resolved?

Comment: The error basically indicates that the you do not have required permission to query the API. Make sure the default authorization mode is set to IAM in the appsync console. Also try with less restrictive IAM policy to check if that is the cause of lacking permission.

Comment: Hi all, I had solved the issue last year only but forgot to update here. I don't remember the exact problem but I had tweeted about the approach I had taken. [Twitter thread](https://twitter.com/swapy_m/status/1053159274581393408?s=20)